# I want to read output from a console-mode child process

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

I am trying to update a program which was written in 1995 with pascal or c. I am not sure about programming language.  Command line program. Now I am coded in C#. And I want to read child program output. Is it possible?

I tried something. But not successful. They are:

```
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "asdd.exe";
        p.Start();


        logs.AppendText("Timer Started\n");
        timer1.Enabled = true;


    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // write somethingg and read what is the program doing on command line?
        // What is the program printint? etc... 
        // I try this code but not enough for mo. 
        // logs.AppendText("d:" + p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()+"\n");

    }

    private void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

I am open to any ideas in java, cpp, c, or c#.

Edit:

For example:

My asdd.exe program source code is

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("something\n");
    printf("something, too\n");
}
```

This program call with C# and logs richTextBox is appended with:

```
something
something, too
```

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you wanna read text from the console or do you wanna obtain the parameters that were passed to your program?

Comment: I've seen this question before... wait, are you wanting to see the content (source code or memory or something) of your program spit out on the command-line (ala a quine), which is what your title says, or you're wanting to get the content of the command line into your program, which is what the code snippet suggests?

Comment: i am trying to update a program. I am designing a GUI in C#. And use old program to process some actions. In this situation, I am read some information from old program. Old program was written in 1995 and source code was loss.

Comment: i want to read program content. Not want to use argv or not want to send any argument to program.

Comment: @Alexandre: I've updated your question to say what I think you mean.  The content of a program is its *code*.  I think you mean the *output* or *results*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to hook up to StandardInput.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx

Comment: i tried that but return me nothing. either i was not able to use or it is not suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

`ReadToEnd` won't return any data until the child program ends.  You might need to read a line at a time or even a character at a time, if you want to see output while the program is running.

Comment: i try and StandardOutput.ReadLine() is not return ant string.

Comment: What happens if you try reading individual characters?  Maybe the other program isn't sending a newline character.  Or maybe you're running into buffering, when the other program detects stdout isn't a console (hopefully not, this is hard to overcome).

Comment: Maybe program is not use, i will try any program which use stdout. And return back.

Comment: I dont understard but I wrote an c program. get a character with scanf and print a sentences  with printf in a while loop. But program is not work with this code. After that I tried with code of @cadrell0, but it doesn't work. Blank black screen.

Comment: @Alexandre: What happens if you run the other program redirected to a file?  Like `program > output.log` (from a command-prompt).

Comment: i am logging them to richTextbox with 

logs.AppendText(  process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() ); 

or

logs.AppendText(  process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() );

i try separately with them. But nothing return me from program.

Comment: @Alexandre: I strongly suggest you test whether shell redirection works right.  If not, there's not much you can do.  If cmd.exe can redirect the output, then C# will be able to as well once you sort out the bugs.

Comment: i understand. i will try again and again, maybe somethings can change.

Comment: @Alexandre: I'm not suggesting to try the same thing again.  Instead of calling the other program from C#, open a command prompt and call it.  Do you get output?  Then try redirecting to a file, in the command prompt?  Does the output go to the screen or to the file.

Comment: hmm. I am getting output from the program, when i call with command line. But not output is gotten if I use c# process.

My output is on screen in my little example program. Not to file.

Comment: @Alexandre: What you're saying is at the command prompt you typed `asdd > result.txt` and the output still appeared on the screen?

Comment: output is not on screen and result.txt is blank. What does that mean? Does not the program has output? or does not use stdout?

Comment: @Alexandre: I think it means the program doesn't use stdout.  I assume with your little test printf application you can redirect to a file without difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I typically read from a seperate process.  Now this will block the current thread until processing is complete, so I use a background thread.

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "program.exe"
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine(data);

string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I tried with code of @cadrell0, but it doesn't work. Blank black screen with any c console application which use scanf,printf functions in while loop.

Comment: i dont use 
`
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
`
to see what to do.

Comment: What exactly does this other process do?  If you were to call it manually, what would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN article seems to be just what you are looking for.

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: in this link, process communicate with together, that's right. but both of the program is written by same person. My problem, i dont have source code one of my programs and i want to read what to do this program which I dont have source code.

Comment: @Alexandre Dominos: If I'm not mistaken, that 2nd program is just for example, and you don't need to specially code the child process. I think it will use the pipes you set up as its stdin and stdout.

Comment: In fact, i want to read a command line program content with c#. My application is written in c#. I have not written it, yet but i will write in c#. The command Line program is exe only. Example program represent to this command line program. So, command line program is only exe not to allow change source. If you want to say "read stdin/stdout with a pipe" it is good idea. I will try.

Comment: @Alexandre Dominos: I just noticed a comment on that page about how legacy programs may end up buffering their output in a way the would not on the command line. Apparently a workaround is to start cmd.exe as the child process and use that to indirectly launch the actual child process you want.